# Integration of $x^{sin x}$

Tags: calculus

I have tried substitution method but it does not help

how to integrate a function of the form
$x^{sin x}$

Also how to tntegrate a function of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Thank you

Vasudevan

Comment: If you can only work with elementary functions, you cannot integrate that...

Comment: Your function doesn't have a clean indefinite integral, sorry

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, there is no antiderivative.

Let us suppose that what you need is to approximate
$$I=\int_0^a x^{\sin (x)}\,dx$$ where $a$ is a small number. You can expand the integrand using Taylor expansion an get, for example
$$x^{\sin (x)}=1+x \log (x)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \left(\log ^3(x)-\log
   (x)\right)+\frac{1}{24} x^4 \left(\log ^4(x)-4 \log
   ^2(x)\right)+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Integrating termwise (you will need quite a lot of integration by parts but it is perfectly doable), you should get
$$\int x^{\sin (x)}\,dx=x+x^2 \left(\frac{\log (x)}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{54} x^3 \left(9 \log
   ^2(x)-6 \log (x)+2\right)+\frac{1}{768} x^4 \left(32 \log ^3(x)-24 \log ^2(x)-20
   \log (x)+5\right)+\frac{x^5 \left(625 \log ^4(x)-500 \log ^3(x)-2200 \log
   ^2(x)+880 \log (x)-176\right)}{75000}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ 
Trying for a few values of $a$ and comparing to some accurate numerical integrations, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 0.1 & 0.087104 & 0.087104 \\
 0.2 & 0.162658 & 0.162661 \\
 0.3 & 0.233734 & 0.233753 \\
 0.4 & 0.303550 & 0.303607 \\
 0.5 & 0.374214 & 0.374332 \\
 0.6 & 0.447366 & 0.447552 \\
 0.7 & 0.524418 & 0.524655 \\
 0.8 & 0.606646 & 0.606897 \\
 0.9 & 0.695221 & 0.695449 \\
 1.0 & 0.791201 & 0.791404
\end{array}
\right)$$ which does not seem too bad.

For sure, we could add more terms for more accuracy but it will start to be quite tedious.